# Custom post listing page layout of custom post type

Tags: wordpress

[image]

What is the best way to customise the standard wordpress custom post listing layout. To be specific, I am trying to add a subheading just below the **Lessons / Create New Lesson** button but before **All (0) | Trash (1)**

Is this possible with just a wordpress plugin or i have to modify core file OR maybe create a theme.

If it's possible, how much of this page is customizable by a plugin.

I would prefer a plugin solution.

Comment: This is customizable with a plugin and can be customized as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks hey, can you please point me in the right direction........i want to add markup at a certain position

Comment: You have to checkout few tutorials about it , here is one of them : http://www.instantshift.com/2012/03/06/21-most-useful-wordpress-admin-page-hacks/